# Flag/Unflag shortcut in mail.app

Tags: snow-leopard, mail.app

I learned that <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in mail.app should toggle the flag of a selected message. However, it doesn't work for me... I'm using Snow Leopard and Mail 4.5. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem in my case was that there was a conflict between the cmd-shift-l of mail.app and cmd-l which I use to change the input language... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you found a solution, please post it as an answer so that other people can find the solution. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd-L` was set as the *input source* shortcut. This caused a conflict with the `cmd-shift-L` of mail.app. Once I have changes the input source shortcut (to `cmd-M`) and restarted mail.app everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

In Lion the shortcut is exactly that and you can actually take a look at the menu:

[image]

Make sure you're using the right one. If you wanted to alter those, you'd have to go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts and add a new one:

[image]

Comment: I explicitly wrote that I'm not using Lion... Anyway, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Dror I know you were using Snow Leopard (I actually added the tag to your question) but I was suspecting that you had a Keyboard Shortcut conflict, and hence why I posted the info. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Somehow I didn't understand it from your answer... I thought it was Lion oriented. Anyway - thanks for the hint and help!